# Valgrind "Invalide write of size 1"

Tags: c, string, valgrind

Below I wrote a function`_getstr()`, to get string in input without using `scanf`. Running valgrind, however, results "Invalid write of size 1" error. This happens for each input. What causes this error?

```c
char *_getstr(){
    char *str = NULL;
    int bufsize = 0, c = 0;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != '\n'){
            str = realloc(str, (bufsize + 1)*sizeof(char));
            str[bufsize++] = c;
        }
    } while (c != '\n');
    str[bufsize] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

In main I do that:

```c
char *s1 = _getstr();
```

The output of valgrind when I insert the input is this:

```
Insert of the first string: hello
==6830== Invalid write of size 1
==6830==    at 0x109294: _getstr (changeJOIN.c:43)
==6830==    by 0x10919B: main (changeJOIN.c:15)
==6830==  Address 0x4a419b4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6830==    at 0x4839D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==6830==    by 0x109264: _getstr (changeJOIN.c:39)
==6830==    by 0x10919B: main (changeJOIN.c:15)
```

Comment: Extending the buffer for *each* character is really expensive! You should use a geometric sequence for the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the terminating null byte, `str` points to `bufsize` bytes, so `str[bufsize] = '\0';` writes one element past the end of allocated memory.  This is what valgrind it complaining about.

You need to allocate one more byte before adding the null terminator.

```
str = realloc(str, (bufsize + 1)*sizeof(char));
str[bufsize] = '\0';
```